# SQL Server 2008 R2 installation Error "Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller"

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, installation

Im getting an error half way through an SQL Server 2008 r2 installation. The error states

Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller.

it asks to retry or cancel. Upon trying both, the error message returns and I must cntrl-alt-delete to end the process. I have checked all permissions associated with local account, network domain account and ran installation as administrator. I have searched on the web and other people are having this problem too but I cant find a solution. so I turn to the experts, anyone encounter this error??

Comment: Can you post the options that you're selecting for installation?  Which services (db engine, SSAS, SSIS, etc), named or default instance, etc.

Comment: just a default instance and server management studio. SQL 2008 R2 express X32 on windows 7 32bit

Comment: I have also tried going to local security policy > local policies > user rights assignment  and adding the account I am installing on to the following policies: Back up files and directories, debug programs, take ownership of files or other objects, manage auditing and security log. as described in http://www.bradg.co.za/?p=12

Comment: Are you running the install from a remote location or is the installer on your local drive?  I've seen this be an issue before, where it really wants to be local.

Comment: from downloads on c:

Comment: How can I clean up the pieces that all of these installations are leaving. I have tried the install so many times and every time I do it goes half way through and fails. It seems to install the instance but never the management studio. I have a feeling that at least part of the problem is the pieces the installation is leaving behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon some more research I found the answer. Im not sure why but the admin account didn't have ownership of the program files File. this was causeing a problem when installing the SQL Server 2008 R2. Here are the steps that ultimately fixed my issue.

1. Change UAC settings to NEVER NOTIFY
2. reboot
3. Take Ownership of the Program Files File with the admin account

   - Right click Program File --> Properties --> Security Tab --> Advanced --> Owner TAB --> Edit --> Check "Replace owner on subcontainers & Objects"
4. Reboot
5. Add Full control permission to the admin account to Program File
6. Reboot

Boom Baby!

http://www.radiodj.ro/community/index.php?topic=2445.0

Answer (score 2):

I got this error with SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 10.

Weirdly, copying the installer file from my downloads directory to my desktop fixed the error.

Comment: This helped and it is weird indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this error too while trying to restore my ACL's with "icacls" command. But when i ran PowerShell as administrator (i dunno why i should do this, coz i've already was logged on under "Administrator" account) it just begins to work normally. Maybe it helps you.

Comment: Running Powershell as admin elevates that process to admin. It's similar to the concept of sudo on Unix

Answer (score 0):

Robin is right.

I run into these very classic errors trying to install SQL Server 2012 Express under Windows Server 2012 R2:

1/ Error installing SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
Error code: 0x84BB0001

2/ Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller.
This error message appears 6 times during installation.

Also:

SQL Server logs and event viewer shows it tried to open this database on a non existant volume:
e:\sql11_main_t.obj.x86release\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\MSDBLog.ldf

SQL Server service cannot be started manually

SQL Server setup program was initially downloaded with IE and saved on:
C:\Users\Public\Downloads\ ... (public access)

Copying the installer file to the administrator desktop and running it solved all these issues.

Years ago I found similar SQL Server installer errors when the installer file was located on another volume than C:

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install MSSQL Server 2008 R2 after uninstalling any higher or lower version of MSSQL Server i.e MS SQL Server 2012,2014. Please make sure that you have removed every single file with the name SQL Server except the following three files from the control panel >> Programs >> Uninstall a Program.

```
Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU
Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 Query Tool ENU
Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 x64 ENU CTP1
```

Also, removed the MSSQL Server folder from the following path

```
C:\Program Files\
C:\Program Files(x86)
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft
```

After then restart the system and try to install it.

Please let me know if you receive any errors.